# Jquery how to Concat value which are separated by space

Tags: jquery

```
facetHtml + = "<li id=" + data.facets[key].displayName + "><h3>" + data.facets[key].displayName + "</h3>";
```

I want to Concat the displayName name as it comes space separated which will not work in li Id.  For example Display name is "Product Type" or "Die ID"

Comment: use `split()` and combine them?

Comment: The issue isn't the concatenation (which is working fine) the problem is that `id` attributes cannot have spaces. You need to either remove those spaces or replace them with another character.

Comment: you can use `.replace(" ","")` - replace space with nothing in `displayName`

Comment: ya, But I can just use displayName name no other option I have to do some operation further using the li Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't the concatenation (which is working fine) the problem is that `id` attributes cannot have spaces.

You need to either remove those spaces

```
facetHtml + = "<li id=" + data.facets[key].displayName.replace(/\W/g, '') + "><h3>" + data.facets[key].displayName + "</h3>";
```

Or replace them with another character.

```
facetHtml + = "<li id=" + data.facets[key].displayName.replace(/\W/g, '-') + "><h3>" + data.facets[key].displayName + "</h3>";
```

Note that the use of a regular expression here (`/\W/g`) will capture and replace *all* spaces in the string. Using a simple replace on a space (`' '`) will only replace the first instance.

Comment: why not use just .replace(" ","")

Comment: @SachinPrasad see the note at the bottom of my answer. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tp263cpm/1/

Answer (score 0):

"ID" should not contain spaces.

Consider using .trim(x) or .replace(x,y) to remove spaces before processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.facets[key].displayName.split(" ").join('')
```

Comment: Please clarify your answer instead of just posing a code snippet. Answers like these tend to get down-voted and/or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
data.facets[key].displayName.replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: This may be the correct answer but it is considered a good practice to add some clarifications to your answer instead of just posting a code snippet. Answers like these tend to get down-voted and/or deleted.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic thanks of you commented i will improve that you commented

Answer (score 0):

u can try this removing all the spaced from name

```
 facetHtml + = "<li id=" + data.facets[key].displayName.replace(/\W/g, '-') + "><h3>" + data.facets[key].displayName + "</h3>";
```

it will remove all spaced in ur data (display name) and will make the id